# Passing an object as argument to a Class constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, arguments

I'm trying to migrate from Python and PyQt to C++ and Qt. I've started with some basic OOP but I've stumbled upon this:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "src/gpoint.h"
#include "src/gquadrilateral.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Running..." << std::endl;
    GPoint origin1(23, 50);
    GQuadrilateral rectangle1(origin1, 100, 100);
    std::cout << "Finished..." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### gpoint.h

```
#ifndef GPOINT_H
#define GPOINT_H

class GPoint {

    public:
        GPoint(int x = 0, int y = 0);
        int x();
        int y();
        ~GPoint();

    protected:

    private:
        int m_x;
        int m_y;

    };

#endif
```

#### gquadrilateral.h

```
class GPoint;

class GQuadrilateral {

    public:
        GQuadrilateral(GPoint origin, int width, int height);
        int width();
        int height();
        ~GQuadrilateral();

    protected:

    private:
        int m_width;
        int m_height;

    };
```

I'm trying to pass a GPoint object to the GQuadrilateral constructor. I'm getting the following linking error:

```
Building target: geometrix.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++  -o "geometrix.exe"  ./src/gpoint.o ./src/gquadrilateral.o  ./main.o   
./main.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/d/workspaces/geometrix/Debug/../main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `GQuadrilateral::GQuadrilateral(GPoint, int, int)'
/cygdrive/d/workspaces/geometrix/Debug/../main.cpp:21:(.text+0x109): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `GQuadrilateral::GQuadrilateral(GPoint, int, int)'
makefile:45: recipe for target 'geometrix.exe' failed
/cygdrive/d/workspaces/geometrix/Debug/../main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `GQuadrilateral::~GQuadrilateral()'
/cygdrive/d/workspaces/geometrix/Debug/../main.cpp:21:(.text+0x148): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `GQuadrilateral::~GQuadrilateral()'
/cygdrive/d/workspaces/geometrix/Debug/../main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `GQuadrilateral::~GQuadrilateral()'
/cygdrive/d/workspaces/geometrix/Debug/../main.cpp:24:(.text+0x178): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `GQuadrilateral::~GQuadrilateral()'
/cygdrive/d/workspaces/geometrix/Debug/../main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `GQuadrilateral::~GQuadrilateral()'
/cygdrive/d/workspaces/geometrix/Debug/../main.cpp:21:(.text+0x189): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `GQuadrilateral::~GQuadrilateral()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [geometrix.exe] Error 1
```

Can you give me a hint, please?




Edit 1: added conditional directives in **gpoint.h**;

Comment: Did you add `#include "gpoint.h"` to your gquadrilateral.h file?  Also, make sure you add `#ifndef GPOINT_H #define GPOINT_H` to the beginning of gpoint.h and then `#endif` at the end of the file.

Comment: You need to include `gpoint.h` in `gquadrilateral.h`. Don't redefine the class in `gquadrilateral.h` either.

Comment: that is a linker error

Comment: For those guys muttering about the header: Yes you are right, thats not good but this shouldnt cause a linker error and isnt actually a problem as far as i can tell, as he includes the header in the compilation unit (main.cpp).

Comment: @Namfuak If I do that I get `../src/gpoint.h:2:7: error: redefinition of 'class GPoint` and it tells me that I've already include it in `In file included from ../main.cpp:2:0:` which is kinda true.

Comment: because you have to use header guards: http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/c241man/node90.html , on a win plattform you can also write `#pragma once` wouldnt recommend you that though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that the constructor is not implemented at all, just declared, or that you havent linked against the libraries or objects which contain this specific constructor. (The same applies to the desctructor aswell by the way).

Comment: Yes, you are right, seems like _someone_ commented some lines in the *.cpp files :D. With the current implementation **GQuadrilateral(GPoint origin, int width, int height);** the value of the **origin** parameter can be modified inside the **GQuadrilateral** class? Thanks.

Comment: No it cant, as origin is copied / a temporary. Use a pointer (`GPoint*`) or reference (`GPoint&`) instead. To be more precise: You CAN modify it inside your function but your changes will not reflect to the outside as the parameter you are working with is a copy and not related to the passed argument anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could be missing the stage in which objects are linked together. In that case you have to run

```
  `g++ -Wall -pedantic -c gpoint.c
   g++ -Wall -pedantic -c gquadrilateral.c
   g++ -Wall -pedantic -c main.c
   g++ -Wall -pedantic -o output main.o gpoint.o gquadrilateral.o`
```

to link all objects together.

Comment: That's ok... I wrote 12 minutes ago.. at that time a linker problem could be still be there @DaddyPumpkin